# If another variable in ChangeNotifier is changed, will the Consumer's model be updated?

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-change-notifier, flutter-riverpod

If the following setIntVal is called and notifyListeners(); is executed, is the Text redrawn? intVal is changed but strVal is not.

Similarly, what happens when StateNotifier is used?

```
class DummyManager with ChangeNotifier {
  DummyManager();

  int intVal = 0;
  String strVal = "";

  void setIntVal(val) {
    intVal = val;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

Consumer<DummyManager>(
    builder: (context, model, child) {
      return Text(model.strVal);
    },
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. By default, any change in a notifier rebuilds a consumer.

But you can optimize this, using `select`:
By changing your consumer to:

```dart
Consumer(
  builder: (context, ref, child) {
    final strVal = ref.watch(modelProvider.select((v) => v.strVal));
    return Text(strVal);
  },
)
```

Then your widget will rebuild only when that specific value changes.

Do note that the result is expected to be immutable. As such, avoid retuning lists

Comment: Wow. We didn't expect to get a reply from you. That's a great mechanism. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

yes of course redrawn, and notify all listeners and by the end consumer have a listener to do this

Comment: Ah. I see.
We'll have to break up the ChangeNotifier and StateNotifier into smaller pieces to minimize redraws.

Answer (score 1):

You modify your `state` object in your `StateNotifier` class and the interface is redrawn. Just have to consider that the new `state` must be a new object and immutable

Comment: So if we update the state object in the StateNotifier class, it will be redrawn? I understand.

Comment: Yes. And in this class you can put additional logic and many-many methods. Everything that is responsible for the state will be in this class.